Undefined behavior with pointer casts in C99 and MISRA C:2012
I'm working on a C99 project that requires us to follow the MISRA C:2012 standard.
Rule 11.3 essentially prevents from casting a pointer between different object types without declaring a justified exception an approved deviation (in accordance with MISRA Compliance).
The reasoning behind this seems to be to prevent undefined behavior in case of

misaligned pointers
accessing an object with a "wrong" type (refers to C99 6.5 paragraph 7)

It looks to me like point 2 is just about the strict aliasing rule (at least the footnote on the referenced C99 paragraph indicates this).
I would argue that both do not matter in this particular project because...

the underlying processor (Cortex-M7) can handle unaligned access
type-based alias analysis and related strict alias optimization is disabled

Am I missing some potentially undefined behavior or is this a valid justification to violate this rule?

edit:
I agree with you that it's code smell and it breaks portability. Moreover, I see that depending on how and where the memory access is done, alignment issues could still be possible.
But just to add a bit of context: I'm dealing with code that already exists and just has a very poor justification for this deviation. Changing it because of code smell isn't really an option due to the process overhead involved. But if there's a real problem, e.g. due to undefined behavior, that would be a different thing. If I were completely free to rewrite the code, I would definitely want to write it in a way without breaking this rule.

Apart from the mentioned reasons, casting between different object types might also be "code smell" (with casts to unsigned char*/uint8_t* being a valid exception). So what you should be asking is rather: what is a valid justification to do such pointer casts in the first place? What's the use case and why can't you solve it with better design instead of a cast?

Regarding Cortex M7, it cannot necessarily handle unaligned access. See https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0646/c/The-Cortex-M7-Instruction-Set/About-the-instruction-descriptions/Address-alignment As a C programmer, you have no control over which instructions that will get generated and you probably shouldn't assume that the compiler can spot a misaligned access and generate instructions accordingly.

Please note that even if core would support unaligned access, memory you are accessing might not. Modern MCUs have multiple different memory areas, and some might have more access restrictions than others.

About the "Cortex-M7": MISRA is also about portability. Even if your processor can do magically handle all your flaws, your code will fail on an other processor that perhaps can not do that.

Whoever "corrected" my edit that references MISRA Compliance to be MISRA C:2012 Compliance please leave it alone... thanks!

@Andrew The OP changed it. And for all we know, the OP might be following MISRA C:2012 (with or without the TC:s). Personally I still maintain lots of projects where I'm stuck with MISRA C:2004 even :/

The main reasons not to allow such casts are misalignment and "strict aliasing" indeed, both invoking undefined behavior. We can tell since on top of rule 11.3, there's the cryptic note

C11 [Undefined 25, 37]

This is a strange, somewhat fishy MISRA thing where you are supposed to open up Annex J of ISO C11 and count in the summary list of UB there.
(Which is questionable since Annex J is informative and also known to be filled with mistakes that never get corrected, many sitting there since C99. A lot of Annex J states that something in is UB and then points to completely irrelevant normative parts that do not justify or even mention the supposed UB at all. Annex J is not to be trusted - I can dig up a bunch of various mistakes in it if prompted.)
"Undefined 25" being misalignment UB, and "Undefined 37" being effective type/strict aliasing UB.
Notably rule 11.3 has an exception for a conversion to (but not from) a pointer to character type, because then neither alignment nor strict aliasing apply.

Is it valid to deviate?
In embedded systems there are some rare oddball situations where wild & crazy pointer casts may be motivated. Flash/eeprom drivers for example might require that you write C which boils down to 16 bit or 32 bit access, based on an incoming byte stream.
Another valid reason to deviate from the rule would be object pointer conversions from the first member of a struct to/from a pointer to that struct, which is well-defined by C and a common use-case, yet not listed as an exception in 11.3.
Other situations could be when implementing stuff like memcpy or memory pools in C and you need to type pun from character type to a larger type.


the underlying processor (Cortex-M7) can handle unaligned access

Yes, no, maybe? I'm not an ARM assembler expert but as noted in comments, M7 only allows unaligned access in some situations and we have no control over which assembly instructions that get generated from C. So if you mean to take advantage of the instructions in the link, you need to write inline assembler in which case C language rules and MISRA C are out of scope.

type-based alias analysis and related strict alias optimization is disabled

The amount of possible alias analysis that you can disable varies a lot depending on compiler. It might be hard to make a case stating "yes I have definitely disabled all of it". Sounds like mission impossible if using gcc, for example.

Am I missing some potentially undefined behavior or is this a valid justification to violate this rule?


MISRA C 11.3 makes the example of "casting away qualifiers" as yet another form of UB. This would be UB as per ISO C17 6.7.3 §7 (constraints) and also covered by MISRA 11.8.
There's a couple of separate, sound MISRA rules 11.2 and 11.5 also covering object pointer conversions (from incomplete type and to/from void pointers) that should be considered.


Thanks, that's the kind of statement I was looking for. And btw interesting to know that the C99 annex can be incorrect - so far I took that as "ground truth" and actually got confused at one point when it referred from integer UB to a somewhat unexpected paragraph.

@Smith_33 Particularly questionable is the "the value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate", for which there is no explicit support anywhere in the standard and the ISO WG knows this, since they have debated the concept of indeterminate "wobbly values" plenty. And yet the Annex J paragraph keeps pointing to nonsense chapters, from C99 to C23.

@Lundin: There are many platforms where a declaration like register unsigned short x; would assign a 32-bit register to x, but truncate any value which is written to it to 16 bits.  Even before C99, it would not have been uncommon for an uninitialized x declared as above to behave like a value outside the range 0 to 65535, or for an x which lacks a register storage class specifier but never has its address taken to behave likewise.  The Standard has no terminology for accommodating such things except to characterize as UB all circumstances where they might occur.

@Lundin: Automatic storage duration objects whose values are indeterminate could behave strangely even under some pre-C99 implementations, even though C89 didn't classify use of such objects as UB, and even if their types would normally assign values to all possible bit patterns.

@supercat Oh I see, you weren't commenting on the Q&A but my comment about Annex J being broken. Well the standard does have terminology for it (since C90) and the term is inderminate value. Accessing one leads to unspecified behavior, not undefined. Save for the special case of "could have been declared as register/not having its address taking" which is explicit UB as per C99.

Anyway the point here is that this part of Annex J is plain wrong: "Undefined behavior" "- The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)." None of the quoted chapters contain any relevant text backing up this supposed UB.

@Lundin: Under the "as-if" rule, given unsigned short x; unsigned long y; the only way y=x; could leave y holding a value which isn't in the range 0-65535--as could have happened on some C89 implementations--would be if it invoked UB.  On the other hand, the authors of C89 didn't expect that characterization of something as UB would be given priority over anything else that would specify the behavior, but merely intended it as a warning: "Although some implementations define the behavior of this construct, and should likely continue to do so, others might not."

@supercat If reading an unsigned short and obtaining a value larger than USHRT_MAX, then the compiler is wildly non-conforming to C89 or later, indeterminate value or not.

@Lundin: If an attempt to read an automatic-duration object whose address isn't taken is regarded as Undefined Behavior, there's no requirement that such a read yield a value within range of the type.  If C89 was intended to characterize as UB any actions which would behave strangely on some existing implementations, then annex J2 would be describing something that should have been in the normative text to uphold that intention

@Lundin: See https://godbolt.org/z/5z3cG1hcb for an example; this compiler version is from after C99 was published, but the fact that test1 is treated just like test2 would not have been astonishing to people familiar with MIPS or a similar platform in the 1980s or 1990s.
